# Docker for windows kubernetes helm - add public repo and get mailhog

Tags: kubernetes, windows-10, kubernetes-helm, docker-for-windows

I am using Windows 10 with `docker for windows`.
I have acitve `kubernetes`.
I've downloaded helm from https://github.com/helm/helm/releases and added files to `Windows PATH`.

Now i want to execute:

```
helm install stable/mailhog --generate-name
```

but i get

> Error: failed to download "stable/mailhog" (hint: running 'helm repo update' may help

I am not sure how to add public repo for it.
I tried adding it with:

```
helm repo add mailhog https://kubernetes-charts-incubator.storage.googleapis.com/
"mailhog" has been added to your repositories
helm repo update
```

but the output from `helm install stable/mailhog --generate-name` gives me still the same error.

How can i get `stable/mailhog` this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com` as the helm repo works for me:

```
helm init
helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com

$ helm repo list
NAME    URL                                             
stable  https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com

helm install stable/mailhog --generate-name
```

Comment: What should `helm init` do? It gives me just some help menu. I was not naming the `repo` right in the next command, thanks.

Comment: `helm init` initializes helm.